find element with specific child elements
I'm using Selenide 7.5.1. and Java 20.
I have to know if a particular calendar event (identified by person name, entry and time (eg: Bill Williamson, entry1, 10a)) exists within a set of elements (see below).
I've tried using a for loop to search through all the calendar events, matching the sub-elements but this is a headache and goes against Selenide's recommended practice (ie: don't query elements for information.) I figure there has to be a better way.
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;
        for (SelenideElement element : $$(eventList)) {
            // Check methods of Selenide's Condition class.
            // Find the element that has ce-eventType in the class of a sub-element,
            //   a span.fc-title with the person's name, and a span.fc-time with the correct time.
            if (element.$("class.ce_basicentry").exists() &&
                    element.$("span.fc-time").getText().equalsIgnoreCase(startTime) &&
                    element.$("span.fc-title").getText().equalsIgnoreCase(apuName)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }

I've also tried putting together some kind of WebElementCondition using shouldHave, but I don't know how to create conditions that include sub-elements.
// This doesn't work.
$("dif.fc-event-container").shouldHave(allOf($("a").shouldHave(cssClass(eventType.name())),
                $("span.fc-time").shouldHave(exactText(startTime)),
                $("span.fc-title").shouldHave(exactText(apuName))));

Here's the section of DOM I'm searching.
<div class="fc-event-container">
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end entry1">
        <div class="fc-content">
            <span class="fc-time">8a</span>
            <span class="fc-title"> 
                <i class="uk-icon-justify uk-icon-comment">
                    ::before
                </i>
                Bill Williams
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end entry2">
        <div class="fc-content">
            <span class="fc-time">10a</span>
            <span class="fc-title">
                <i class="uk-icon-justifyicon-ignite-owl">
                    ::before
                </i>  
                Bill Williams
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end entry1">
        <div class="fc-content">
            <span class="fc-time">10a</span>
            <span class="fc-title">
                <i class="uk-icon-justify uk-icon-comment">
                    ::before
                </i>
                Bill Williams
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end entry3">
        <div class="fc-content">
            <span class="fc-time">11a</span>
            <span class="fc-title"> 
                <i class="uk-icon-justify uk-icon-flask">
                    ::before
                </i>
                Bill Williams
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

Is there a good way to do this, or am I limited to using a for loop and cycling through anchor elements?
